Flutter Drawer Menu options aren’t clickable
I'm having an issue with my Flutter app where the Drawer menu becomes unresponsive after using Get.offall(() => HomeView()). I need an experienced Flutter developer who can help me troubleshoot this issue.

The primary function of the Drawer menu is to navigate to different pages. Currently, after calling Get.offall, the menu options become unclickable and I can't redirect to other pages.
The Drawer menu is the default implementation, with no custom modifications.
The issue is isolated to the Drawer menu only.

I would appreciate a solution that restores the menu functionality without the need for excessive calls to Get.back(). Ideally, I am looking for a professional with a deep understanding of Flutter and its routing system.

are you using getx

Yes am using Getx 4.6.6 and GetMaterialApp

it would easier for others if could include minimal-reproducible-example
